# How to organize DirectoryInfo.GetFiles() 

Tags: vb.net, .net

So I have the following lines of code

```
Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(path)
    Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("*." & filetype)
```

Is it possible to have the elements be prearranged according to there file name, the way its organizing the files now, is that there's a couple of number showing up in the wrong order. I'm asking this since I basically to determine if a file is missing in a directory. I'm determining this by subtracting one files name from another. An example of a file name would be 1.0001.tif 1.0002.tif 2.0001.tif and so on. The whole determining the document id number and the decimal is the page number of the document

Comment: You can use LINQ to order the files (or simply `diar1.Sort()`). If you would give us more informations we could show you an example. What is `filetype` exactly?

Comment: .sort() was totally what I was looking for can't belive I missed that thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to order your files:

```
var tifs = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.tif", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Select(fn => new { fn, name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn) })
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.fn,
        x.name,
        major = int.Parse(x.name.Split('.')[0]),
        minor = int.Parse(x.name.Split('.')[1])
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.major).ThenBy(x => x.minor);
```

Note that you need to add `using System.Linq` and that this is yet not fail-safe. It requires the files always to have this format, otherwise `int.Parse` will throw (you could use `int.TryParse`).

You can use a foreach to enumerate the result:

```
foreach(var x in tifs)
    Console.WriteLine("File:{0}", x.fn);
```

Edit: But you can also simply use `diar1.Sort()`(as mentioned in my comment) if you just want to order alphabetically.